# How to sort a list of lists according to another list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

There is a python list:

```
the_list = [[324, 76, "Spain"], [543, 43, "Canada"], [654, 99, "Italy"], [72, 34, "France"],[12, 34, "Italy"],[764, 43, "Spain"],[876, 43, "France"],[732, 22, "Italy"]]
```

and a sorter list:

```
sorter_list = ["Italy", "Spain", "Canada", "France"]
```

`the_list`  should be sorted according to order of countries in `sorter_list` , and then it sould be sorted by 2nd item of each inner list descending, while preserving the country order:

```
sorted_list = [[654, 99, "Italy"], [12, 34, "Italy"], [732, 22, "Italy"], [324, 76, "Spain"], [764, 43, "Spain"], [543, 43, "Canada"], [876, 43, "France"], [72, 34, "France"]]
```

I know itemgetter can be used but how to do it when a second list is involved?

Comment: `the_list.sort(key=lambda x: sorter_list.index(x[2]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d` is a dictionary with index of `sorter_list` which help to sort the `the_list`.

```
d = {v:i for i, v in enumerate(sorter_list)}
result = sorted(the_list, key=lambda x: d.get(x[2]))

print(result)
# [[654, 99, 'Italy'],
   [12, 34, 'Italy'],
   [732, 22, 'Italy'],
   [324, 76, 'Spain'],
   [764, 43, 'Spain'],
   [543, 43, 'Canada'],
   [72, 34, 'France'],
   [876, 43, 'France']]
```